# Delphi 7 TAdoQuery too slow

Tags: sql-server, delphi-7, ado, tadoquery

I'm using Delphi 7 and SQL Server 2008. The connection is AdoConnection and the Query component I'm using is TAdoQuery.

When i run the following simple query in sql server

```
select FMStreamid, Latitude, Longitude, RealTime from tblFMStream where vehicleid = 2
```

it takes 2 sec to execute in sql server (see pic)
[sql server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8RTI.png)

However running the same query in Delphi takes around 15 seconds to Open.
Does anyone know how to speed that? Thanks

Comment: You can't compare execution time from a database layer to the execution time in a program

Comment: I'm comparing them to show that the problem is not in the query itself, as would most of the answers suggest.

Comment: Well after checking all the Delphi code you provided I must say I cannot see any problems there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They extra time from Delphi is probably a combination of the provider that AdoConnection is using and dataset events being fired when you open your query

Comment: Yes you are right and in addition using _recordset instead of TAdoQuery speeds things up